# Python Nonetype list index in super class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, indexing, superclass

There are 3 classes in my program, and I'm using super class to inherit variables from two base classes. Class A builds 2 lists containing numbers, and it draws number and used in its functions. To indexing which and how many time the numbers to be drawn, the mechanism is built in class B's loop. The number of iteration is determined by variables `initX` and `algorithmIndex`. For each iteration of the loop, class A draw a number from each `ls1` and `ls2` with index `ls[initX]` `ls[initX]`. `Class New` need to inherit from both `class A` and `class B`. But `initX` and `algorithmIndex` give a `Nonetype` at `class New`. I expect that the values of `algorithmIndex` and `Nonetype` can be the same as in `class B`. And I don't know why it happens, aren't these two variables just inherit from `class A`? What is a good solution for that?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
ls1 = [1,2,3,4]
ls2 = [3,4,5,6]
algorithmIndex = None
initX = None

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, algorithmIndex, initX):
         self.algorithmIndex = algorithmIndex
         self.x = ls1[initX] #iniX is used as list index, which return a Nonetype in the new class.
         self.y = ls2[initX]
         self.ls1_history = []

         if self. algorithmIndex == 1:
             self.x1 = self.x
             self.ls1_history.append(self.x1)
         else:
             pass


class B(object):
   def __init__(self, arg):
         algorithmIndex = 1
         while algorithmIndex < 4: 
            initX = 0
            while initX < 4:
               self.q.append(A(algorithmIndex, initX)) #initX needs to be included as an argument in class A. 
               initX += 1
         algorithmIndex += 1

   def midpt(self):
         i = 0
         while i < 4:
            mid = self.q[i].ls1_history
            i+=1


class New(A,B):
    def __init__(self, arg, algorithmIndex, initX):
         A.__init__(self, algorithmIndex, initX)
         B.__init__(self, arg)
         self.initX = A.initX
         self.algorithmIndex = A.algorithmIndex
```

error:

```
 self.x = ls1[initX]
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

Comment: The code you posted produces a different error; please fix that.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are creating an instance of `New`. However, your classes are a bit strange. In `B` you have  `self.q.append` but that class hasn't defined a `q` attribute. And in `New` what's `B.arg`, and what do you expect `A.initX` and `A.algorithmIndex` to be?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for you pointing out, I was just trying too much to make it concise.

Comment: Change `initX` to 0